# SignalR HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Tags: c#, razor, signalr

Im working on a razor pages app hosted in azure. I have created the app and added signalR to the app and test it locally and it runs just fine no issues. Once i publish/deploy it i am getting error:
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for
HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Not sure why it would work locally on local host and once deployed it throws this error.  I assumed maybe i left a line of code out referencing the script but it is there in my file like this:

```
<script src="~/js/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>

<script src="~/js/SignalRUtil.js"></script>
```

so it is there. Any help would be great thanks!